# DataTrigger does not work as expected

Tags: wpf, styles, datatrigger

I have a `ComboBox` bound to a ViewModel property called `Property`.

`Property` is a TypeDescriptor.

When user changes the value in the `ComboBox`, the `Property` is updated.

On the UI i would like to either hide or make visible different controls: textbox, combobox, date picker etc.

Problem is, the `DataTrigger` is not working as expected.

```
<Style x:Key="textboxStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Property.PropertyType}"
                             Value="{x:Type Type={x:Type sys:String}}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: There's no way for WPF to know if PropertyType has changed or not. It's not a DP.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to write a Converter which gets invoked when the value of 'Property' changes. The converter can be a 'TypeDescriptior to Visibility converter. 
The reason why the above doesnt work is because 'PropertyType' doesnt trigger INotifyPropertyChanged.